# Why won't SFML run on my computer?

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

Okay, so I have my program which works on my laptop, my old desktop, and the computers at school. However I am having a problem in that it will not run on my new computer. The program compiles, but nothing happens when I run it... Only a terminal window pops up. It does not even run the main() loop (or, rather, it does not print what I tell it to at the beginning of the main loop). I ran it on my laptop, and that works perfectly. Is it possible for my computer to not be compatible with SFML? My computer seems to run fine otherwise...
Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Code:

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"Meow"<<endl;
    GameLoad();
    cout<<"Loaded"<<endl;
    while (Window.IsOpen())
    {
        Animate();
        Window.Clear();
        Display();
        Window.Display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code? How'd you link it? This question is too vague to be answered in its current form.

Comment: I compiled it with MinGW.  I use NotePad...  I don't know what you mean by how did I link it...  However, here's the main loop of my code:
<code>
int main()
{
 cout<<"Meow"<<endl;
 GameLoad();
 cout<<"Loaded"<<endl;
 while (Screen::Window.IsOpened())
 {
  Animate();
  Screen::Window.Clear();
  Display();
  Screen::Window.Display();
 }
 return 0;
}
</code>

Comment: @KyleMartin: Please just edit your question and put your code in there. Also, did you build it on your laptop and copy the `.exe` over to your other computer? If so, did you copy the Release build? Does your computer have the right runtime libraries? Are the SFML DLLs in the same folder as your program? (I'm assuming Windows here...)

Comment: Code on one line? Seriously? When do you think you'll get around to putting some effort in to formatting this question so that it is legible?

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel  Gosh...  Please...  I understand that it looked ugly, but I didn't realize how to do it on this form...  It's much easier on cplusplus.com.

Comment: @Cornstalks I did both.  I made it on one computer, tried running the .exe on the new one, nothing. I tried compiling on the new computer, no errors, but still didn't do anything except opening the terminal window.  I don't know how to change from debug to release and the other way around in MinGW. And I am running it off my flash drive, in both cases.

Comment: Does the following code work? `int main(){cout<<"A"<<endl;}` Not sure if the problem is related to SFML.

Comment: @LBg Yes, I made a non-SFML program that works perfectly.  However, with my SFML program, it appears never to even reach int main();

Comment: @KyleMartin, what if you do a non-SFML program but link to SFML? This is odd..

Comment: @LBg Okay, I tried that.  No errors!  But what does that mean?  Is it possible that creating the window is giving me issues?  I have it created in a namespace before main...  Hmmmm...  Could that be it?